# printf a number of times from user input

Tags: c, cs50

I'm doing cs50. I'm completely new to C. I am using my limited knowledge of Python but there are some syntax I don't understand.

How do I get it to print a number of times based on user input? why doesn't `void cough(int n = get_int("number: "))` work? It gives me a `use of undeclared identifier 'n'` error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void cough(int n);

int main(void)
{
    cough(n);
}

void cough(int n = get_int("number: "))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("cough\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: if something works in one language, that doesn't mean it would work for another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all there is no variable by the name 'n' in the (local or global) in the main function, you can't pass a variable as argument unless you declared it, declare it first and only than pass it to the function.
Second you can't assign a value to a variable in the function declaration, In python this assignment means that it will be a default value, but in c this is not allowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void cough(int n);

int main(void)
{
   int n = 0;
   cough(n);
}

void cough(int n)
{
   n = get_int("Enter an integer: ");
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       printf("cough\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialise a variable for a method like that in C.  Instead, assign the variable in your `main` function and pass it through to `cough` using `scanf`.

```
printf("Enter the value to be stored in n: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("n= %d",n);
```

`scanf` reads data from `stdin` and stores them according to the parameter format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments.

Syntax is: `int scanf ( const char * format, ... );`